# Angular Material spinner does not work on synchronous calls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a synchronous call `new SyncRequestClient().Post<HistoricoModel,Response>(solrRequest, request);` and I need a spinner to be created for that call. Appear before the call is made and disappear after the call using the AngularMaterial component `<mat-progress-spinner>` or `<mat-spinner>`, however it does not work, the spinner never appears.`

html

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="spinnerVisible"></mat-spinner>
```

component.ts

```
public spinnerVisible: boolean = false;

 public sendGetDocumentosAllPages(pesquisa, tipo) {
    this.spinnerVisible = true;
    response = new SyncRequestClient().get<Response>(solrRequest);
    this.spinnerVisible = false;
    return response;
}
```

The query takes a long time to execute, but the spinner never appears.

Comment: Before call turn spinner on then call changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Comment: Thanks for solve my problem. This solution works perfectly.